# Build a Page which shows the Oldest Post with specific Custom Field Value

Tags: loop, query

I have searched all over for a solution to this problem, so forgive me if I was searching for the wrong thing..

I have a Page "**Review**" (slug "**review**").
I have a number of Custom Post Types with a Custom Field called **asset_status**.
I want to be able to go to the URL for the Review Page, and be shown the oldest Custom Post with **waiting** as the value for the **asset_status** Custom Field.
Ideally, I would also like to be able to have "Prev"/"Next" Buttons allow the user to go to the 2nd/3rd/4th Oldest Post with that field value.

I have tried overriding the Page Query through the `pre_get_posts` and `parse_request` hooks. I have had some success with `parse_request`, but have then had trouble getting the site to use the `single.php` template, even though I try and change it through the `template_include` hook (although I wonder whether my test of `is_page( 'review' )` at that stage fails because I overrode the query earlier.

```
add_filter( 'parse_request', function( $query ) {

    // triggered also in admin pages
    if ( is_admin() )
        return $query;

    // you should check also for page slug, because when pretty permalink are active
    // WordPress use 'pagename' query vars, not 'page_id'
    $id = isset($query->query_vars['page_id']) && (int) $query->query_vars['page_id'] === 230;
    // remember to replace "slug" with real page slug
    $name = isset($query->query_vars['pagename']) && $query->query_vars['pagename'] === 'review';

    if ( ( $id || $name ) && !isset( $query->query_vars['error'] ) ) {
        $query->query_vars = array(
            'post_type' => 'asset' ,
            'meta_key' => 'asset_status' ,
            'meta_value' => 'waiting' ,
            'post_status' => 'publish' ,
            'posts_per_archive_page' => 1 ,
            'orderby' => 'date' ,
            'order' => 'ASC' ,
            'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
        );
    }

    return $query;
});

add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ){

    if ( is_page( 'review' )  ) {
        die('THIS IS THE REVIEW PAGE');
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'single.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template )
            return $new_template;
    }

    return $template;

}, 99 );
```

Any advice, direction or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: As you're in a page, there is no need to use either of these filters as you can set the arguments for the loop you want. I don't have the time now to write a detailed answer, but using a custom `WP_Query` inside your _single-review.php_ should work for a start. Then you have to figure out pagination (can be done by `add_rewrite_rule`)

Comment: Thanks @kero. I'd rather just keep the same single.php template rather than have a new one. But I guess I could use a separate one if that is the best/easiest solution.

Comment: Many files that each do something very specific = nice to maintain. Long file with everything in it = lots of searching/trying once you haven't looked at it for a day

Comment: Before I write an answer: Does the review page have content other than the retrieved CPT posts? Or in other words: Do you want to add content via the backend and the posts are supposed to appear somewhere inside there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking advantage of the [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function to modularise the template for the page content. I then used a page-specific template to override the query being used for the body of that page, and invoked the page content template to display it.